# Uso del subjuntivo en oraciones relativas

Tags: subjuntivo

¿Me podríais explicar por favor por qué en la frase (1) se usa el indicativo (tenemos  un antecedente desconocido/irreal) y por qué la segunda frase va en subjuntivo (si sabemos que es Antonio)?

> (1) Es que hay que reconocerlo: el que **nace** con gracia, nace con
>   gracia.
>
> (2) Yo dejé que fuera Antonio el que **decidiera**, porque estaba
>   claro que...

Answer (score 3):

Nota: esta es una respuesta a la segunda pregunta. Editaré la respuesta para incluir la primera pregunta en cuanto encuentre referencias.

En (2) lo importante no es la especificidad del antecedente, sino el que se haya usado un verbo de influencia ("dejar"), que induce el subjuntivo. Este no se limita al verbo inmediatamente subordinado, sino también a otros subordinados a este último (inducción mediata). La [NGLE](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=puKRkokkRqYLmBmg) da un ejemplo muy similar al de la pregunta:

> (25.12d) Se mencionó en esos apartados que los verbos *aceptar, admitir, conceder, garantizar* y otros similares son compatibles con los dos modos. El proceso de inducción modal mediata descrito en el apartado anterior —es decir, el esquema sintáctico en que el subjuntivo se convierte a su vez en inductor modal— se obtiene también en estos casos, como en *Aceptó que Pelias pusiese las condiciones que quisiera* (Reverte, Ulises). Así pues, el modo subjuntivo en *pusiese* está inducido por el verbo *aceptar*, pero es a la vez el inductor del subjuntivo en *quisiera*.

En otras palabras, un verbo subordinado a otro que ya está en subjuntivo también suele ir en subjuntivo. En el segundo ejemplo, "fuera" va en subjuntivo porque los verbos de influencia inducen al subjuntivo, y "decidiera" va en subjuntivo porque está subordinado a "fuera", que está en subjuntivo.

Si se compara el ejemplo de la NGLE con el de la pregunta, se ve un claro paralelismo:

- Aceptó<sup>1</sup> que Pelias pusiese<sup>2</sup> las condiciones que quisiera<sup>3</sup>.
- Yo dejé<sup>1</sup> que fuera<sup>2</sup> Antonio el que decidiera<sup>3</sup>.

1: verbo principal inductor de subjuntivo.
2: primer verbo subordinado afectado por la acción inductora de subjuntivo del verbo principal (1) mediante *inducción inmediata*.
3: segundo verbo subordinado afectado por la acción inductora de subjuntivo de otro verbo en subjuntivo (2) mediante *inducción mediata*.

Si se cambia el verbo inductor de subjuntivo ("dejar") por uno no inductor (por ejemplo, "ver"), el primer verbo subordinado va en indicativo, por lo que a su vez no induce al subjuntivo del segundo verbo subordinado:

- Yo vi<sup>1</sup> que fue<sup>2</sup> Antonio el que decidió<sup>3</sup>.

1: verbo principal no inductor de subjuntivo.
2: primer verbo subordinado en indicativo.
3: segundo verbo subordinado en indicativo.

Answer (score 1):

El primer ejemplo es una afirmación. El indicativo es apropiado.

En el segundo caso se usa el subjuntivo imperfecto porque el verbo de la oración principal está en pasado y la acción en subjuntivo tiene lugar de forma simultánea o posterior a la acción de la oración principal.

Comment: (1) El que **sea** una afirmación no implica necesariamente que se **deba** usar el indicativo. (2)  Se usa el subjuntivo **imperfecto** porque se habla del pasado, pero eso no explica por qué se usa el subjuntivo y no cualquier otro tiempo pasado del indicativo. Cuando la frase está en presente, se sigue necesitando el subjuntivo: "Yo dejo que *sea* Antonio el que *decida*".

Answer (score 0):

1. > El que **nace** con gracia.

   Esto es un hecho. Usamos el indicativo, más bien, el presente simple indicativo para mostrar la permanencia de un hecho.

   Si queremos usar el subjuntivo, su significado se reduce a que aún la acción no sucede (incerteza):

   > El que **nazca** con gracia. (No sabemos cuándo va a nacer.)
2. Yo dejé que fuera Antonio el que **decidiera**.

   Aquí el imperfecto de subjuntivo no se usa por el sujeto, se usa porque no se sabe si la acción se llevó a acabo:

   > Yo dejé que fuera Antonio el que **decidiera**. (No estoy seguro si Antonio decidió o no.)